# Convert bigint epoch in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, epoch, bigint, azure-synapse

I run into trouble when I convert unix epoch timestamp to normal datetime in Azure Data Warehouse:

```
select 
    dateadd(s, convert(bigint, 2551564800), convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00')) as bigint
```

Error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

The value 2551564800 is equal to 09/11/2050.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @Larnu, the question is related to handle the value more than max int value in DATEADD function. The question you pointed to use DATEADD function. It is diff question.

Comment: Thanks for  the suggestion , but i am running this code on Azure Sql Data warehouse and dataadd_big is not supported. is there any other alternative ?

Comment: *"i am running this code on Azure Sql Data warehouse"* Then tag that; as that makes the difference on if this is a duplicate or not.

Comment: thanks, just edited my post as well.

Comment: @AnbarasanDhanushkodi why use a unix timestamp instead of a proper date type? The timestamp should be converted to a `datetime2` during loading, avoiding the need for conversions afterwards.

Comment: @AnbarasanDhanushkodi and `'1-1-1970 00:00:00'` is *not* an ISO8601 date literal either, which means its value depends on the locale. You wouldn't even need that `convert` call if you used a literal in `YYYYMMDD` form.

Comment: Could you have epoch values greater than 5103129600?

Comment: @AnbarasanDhanushkodi come to think of it, you wouldn't need `convert(bigint, 2551564800)` with a bigint *column* either. Where did this value come from? Did you try to pass a Unix timestamp as a *string* to the client? Why not pass a strongly typed *datetime2* or *datetime* parameter? You can probably get rid of the need for conversions if you explain what you actually try to do

Comment: Unfortunately T-SQL now has a `DATEDIFF_BIG` but not yet a `DATEADD_BIG` (or an option to accept `BIGINT` for the argument. You need a two-step approach with `select DATEADD(SECOND, 2551564800 % 3600, DATEADD(HOUR, 2551564800 / 3600, '19700101'))`. (2 billion hours is ~340K years, so this won't overflow for any representable value.)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , the timestamp is coming from source system, we cannot change that.  I get your point on the format of the literal. the covert (bigint, 2551564800) was an attempt to see if change the default int to bigint and the dataadd functions works.

Comment: @AnbarasanDhanushkodi change your loading code to convert it to a `datetime2`. There's no reason to store that bigint in the database. That's the bug, not how `DATEADD` works

Comment: @Larnu thanks , at this point dont see data going beyond 2100. it is good to know the limitation of the function

Comment: @JeroenMostert you suggestion also works great. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* you don't have epoch values greater than `5103129600` (which will allow you you to have dates up to `2106-02-07T06:28:13`) this will work:

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,2551564800 % 2147483647, DATEADD(SECOND,2147483647 * (V.Epoch / 2147483647),'19700101'))
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(bigint,2551564800))) V(Epoch)
```

Comment: I see why you have used the 2147483647 in the code, it is the max value of int data type. Eventhough it has a limit to year 2106, for me it works. i will accept it as solution. Thanks a bunch and thanks to all the contributors.